# “App banner support” in Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps, progressive-enhancement

Where is the "App banner support" setting for progressive web app installation in Chrome Canary 55?

Per [this guide](https://justmarkup.com/log/2016/04/add-to-homescreen-and-the-app-banner/), I'd like to test whether the web app install banner is working correctly on my site.
The article shows its possible to test using the Chrome devtools mobile panel...

[image]

Here are his instructions:

> If you don’t see the “Request app banner…” entry, try the following:
>
> - Update Chrome to the latest version
> - Enable the flag for “Devtools Experiments”
>   chrome flags enable-devtools-experiments and restart Chrome
> - Enable the option “App banner support” in Devtools -> Settings -> Experiments (If you don’t see it, press Shift six times there to get all experiments)
> - Enable the flag for “Add to shelf”
>   chrome://flags/#enable-add-to-shelf

So, I enable the flags, open the devtools, press shift  x6 and I don't see anything in here about "App banner support".

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you mention is relatively dated, and the feature has since been moved and graduated from being a DevTools experiment.

Chrome 53/55 DevTools has an **Application** tab with an **Add to homescreen** link, which triggers the app-install banner if your app meets the criteria outlined below (errors logged to console):

[image: Application tab in Chrome DevTools]

Screenshot of install banner on Chrome 53/55, macOS Sierra:
[image: Chrome screenshot on macOS]

Screenshot of install banner on Chrome 54, Android 6.0.1:
[image]

[More recent (updated 6-Oct-2016) documentation on Web App Install Banners](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/?hl=en) states:

> Chrome automatically displays the banner when your app meets the following criteria:
>
> - Has a [web app manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/) file with:
>
>   - a `short_name` (used on the home screen)
>   - a `name` (used in the banner)
>   - a 144x144 png icon (the icon declarations must include a mime type of image/png)
>   - a `start_url` that loads
> - Has a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers) registered on your site.
> - Is served over [HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https) (a requirement for using service worker).
> - Is visited at least twice, with at least five minutes between visits.
>
> #### Testing the app install banner
>
> The app install banner is only shown after the user visits the page at least twice within five minutes. You can disable the visit-frequency check by enabling the Chrome flag `#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks`. To test on desktop Chrome, you need to enable the Chrome flag `#enable-add-to-shelf`.
>
> Then, as long as you have a manifest (configured correctly), are on HTTPS (or localhost) and have a service worker, you should see the install prompt.